# How to bend/Reshape UIView in a 3d form to achieve a VR form view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avcapturesession, virtual-reality

I want to be able to reshape a UIView (which shows a AVCaptureSession camera) in a form that we see in VR devices, Exactly like the Picture below. Highly appreciate any help, Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that;s how it is supposed to be done. you need to use the ARKit.

Comment: But i really dont wanna make a VR app, its just a camera app which needs to show the camera on two uiviews and show them properly By VR boxes

Comment: Actually. my bad. i confused VR with AR. those are 2 different things. lol.

Comment: True and I guessed you mean VR of course but still, wanted to mention that I dont wanna make a VR project eitherways.